# Does BigQuery has any data limit with Simba ODBC driver?

Tags: google-bigquery

I am planning to use Simba ODBC driver to load the data from BigQuery.
While going through FAQ, I found below statement that stopping me to go ahead.

> These drivers leverage the query interface for BigQuery and don't
>   provide functionality to leverage BigQuery's large scale ingestion
>   mechanisms or export functionality.

Is it feasible to export complete data from a BigQuery table using ODBC driver or is there any limit on the data size (number of rows or volume)?

Answer (score 0):

Per the documentation of [Magnitude Simba drivers for BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/providers/simba-drivers#known_issues_and_faq) as you mentioned:

> These drivers leverage the query interface for BigQuery and don't
> provide functionality to leverage BigQuery's large scale ingestion
> mechanisms or export functionality.

It looks infeasible to export complete data from a BigQuery table using ODBC Driver, thus you should think of using the [BigQuery Storage API](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/storage) for exporting large data from BigQuery if the current [Export jobs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas#export_jobs) quota is not enough for you.

Comment: Thanks for the response, what is the limit with ODBC driver?